# Regex routers in zend framework,how to make merge these routers?

Tags: regex, zend-framework, router, routes

I need to know how can I merge these routers into one?
I want to have just one router instead of these ones.
I appreciate any answer.:)

```
        $route = new Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Regex(
        '([a-z]{2})/(\w+)/(\w+)/(\w+)',
        array('controller'=>'index',
            'action' => 'index',
            'module'=>'default',
            'lang'=>$lang
        ),
        array(
            1=>'lang',
            2=>'module',
            3=>'controller',
            4=>'action'
        )
    );
    $router->addRoute('default_lang_action', $route);

    $route = new Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Regex(
        '([a-z]{2})/(\w+)/(\w+)',
        array('controller'=>'index',
            'action' => 'index',
            'module'=>'login',
            'lang'=>$lang
        ),
        array(
            1=>'lang',
            2=>'module',
            3=>'controller'
           )
    );
    $router->addRoute('default_lang_con', $route);

    $route = new Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Regex(
        '([a-z]{2})/(\w+)',
        array('controller'=>'index',
            'action' => 'index',
            'module'=>'default',
            'lang'=>$lang
        ),
        array(
            1=>'lang',
            2=>'module'
        )
    );
    $router->addRoute('default_lang_mod', $route);

    $route = new Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Regex(
        '([a-z]{2})',
        array('controller'=>'index',
            'action' => 'index',
            'module'=>'default',
            'lang'=>$lang
        ),
        array(
            1=>'lang'
        )
    );
            $router->addRoute('default_lang', $route);
```

Comment: change (.*\w) to ([\w]*)! sry am new to RE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So instead of the four routes you have now, you want one route in which the last three parameters are optional?  Try this regex:

```
'([a-z]{2})(?:/(\w+)(?:/(\w+)(?:/(\w+))?)?)?'
```